# Open a Jupyter notebook within running server from command line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter/IPython notebooks reside in various directories all over my file system. I don't enjoy navigating hierarchies of directories in the Jupyter notebook browser every time I have to open a notebook. In absence of the (still) missing feature allowing to bookmark directories within Jupyter, I want to explore if I can open a notebook from the command line such that it is opened by the Jupyter instance that is already running. I don't know how to do this....

Comment: Sounds like an organization issue.  Is there a problem with starting a jupyter notebook server within each project directory?  This does not require much browser navigation.  I often run many jupyter notebook servers at once without issue.

Comment: I was considering that. But I wasn't sure what the resource overhead was with that approach. Sounds like not much, from what you say.

Comment: It should still work to run `jupyter notebook /path/to/myNotebook.ipynb`. Also commands like `ls ~`, `ls ..` are supported so its easy to check where things are.

Comment: The [nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen) tool does this.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: Run multiple jupyter notebook servers from your project directory root(s).  This avoids navigating deeply nested structures using the browser ui.  I often run many notebook servers simultaneously without issue.

`$ cd path/to/project/; jupyter notebook;`

**Option 2**: If you know the path you could use `webbrowser` module

`$ python -m webbrowser http://localhost:port/path/to/notebook/notebook-name.ipynb`

Of course you could alias frequently accessed notebooks to something nice as well.